# comparing values in 2 arrays in php - array_intersect doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays named investmentprogramscriteria and companyInvestmentProfil:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 55
        [criteriaIsMatchedIf] => 11, 12, 13
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 54
        [criteriaIsMatchedIf] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 52
        [criteriaIsMatchedIf] => 1
    )

)


Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 52
        [investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 54
        [investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 58
        [investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 59
        [investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 55
        [investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer] => 1
    )

)
```

I am trying to find out if the value of the criteriaID from the first array (investmentprogramscriteria ) exists in the second array (companyInvestmentProfil) AND IF the value of the key criteriaIsMatchedIf from the first array is equal to the value of the key investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer from the second array.

My current php code returns wrong result at this time:

```
if (array_intersect($investmentprogramscriteria,$companyInvestmentProfil))     {
    echo "Match";
 } else {
    echo "Not match";
 }
```

Comment: Are the criteriaID unique in each array?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, they should be unique

Comment: `array_intersect` will do a string comparison of the values to see if they are the same. Your values are an array, not a string. It won't recursively go through all levels of an array and compare all keys/values to see what is the same.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn You are right...Any idea how to check if values of the array keys are same as described above?

Comment: If the criteria id is unique, I personally would just index the second array with the criteria id when building it (or loop over and re-build it in that format). Then you can just loop over the first array, check if the criteria id key exists, check the other value and if they match save it into another array.

Answer (score 1):

`array_column()` can extract the column indicated as a single dimension and indexes it by the next column indicated.  Do this for both arrays and then use `array_intersect_assoc()` to check key and value:

```
if(array_intersect_assoc(
array_column($investmentprogramscriteria, 'criteriaIsMatchedIf', 'criteriaID'),
array_column($companyInvestmentProfil, 'investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer', 'criteriaID'))) {
    echo "Match";
} else {
    echo "No Match";
}
```

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php).

Comment: I got Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column() . I am using PHP 5.2.4, I guess that is the reason...Any work arround?

Comment: Holy crap!  That is no bueno.  You should upgrade.  I edited an alternate.

Comment: unfortunately anonymous functions were also added in php 5.3. So looks like you also have to define a function and pass the name by string.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: Well damnit.  I thought we were past all this crap!

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in.... I guess that the reason for this is mentioned in  the comment of the Jonathan Kuhn

Comment: MUCH better to upgrade but use _PHP Implementation of array_column()_ in the edit.

Comment: I get wrong result....I get match, but the values are not the same. Any idea why is that?

Comment: If you get _Match_ then one or more are the same.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I need ALL of them to be the same, not only one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122147/discussion-between-user2417624-and-abracadaver).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code with array_map:

```
$elements1 = array();
foreach($investmentprogramscriteria as $item) {
    $elements1[] = $item['criteriaID'] . $item['criteriaIsMatchedIf'];
}
$elements2 = array();
foreach($companyInvestmentProfil as $item) {
    $elements2[] = $item['criteriaID'] . $item['criteriaIsMatchedIf'];
}

if (array_intersect($elements1, $elements2))     {
    echo "Match";
} else {
    echo "Not match";
}
```

Comment: They are looking for a match on `criteriaID` AND the other column.

Comment: @Andrej Ludinovskov, I am gettingt the following error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in .... I am using PHP 5.2.4, and upgrading is not an option at this time. Any work arround?

Comment: @Andrej Ludinovskov I get an error in line $elements1 = []; Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: Sure, it's too old PHP that doesn't have short syntax for array.

Comment: @Andrej Ludinovskov I get error  Message: Undefined index: criteriaIsMatchedIf... Any idea why is that?